# I just want to get numerical values with regex through the text

Tags: excel, vba, regex-group

I want to get just numeric values from a two-line expression.
Thank you to those who will help now.

```
Sub Test_nLine()
Dim oRegexp, iStr, colMatch, objMatch
Set oRegexp = New regexp
With oRegexp
    .pattern = "\s*([^\r\n]+?)\s*$"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
End With
iStr = "(1234.00.01.01, 5678.03 " & vbLf & " and 1234.00.02 excluding)"
Set colMatch = oRegexp.Execute(iStr)
For Each objMatch In colMatch
    Debug.Print objMatch.SubMatches.item(0)
Next                                                                                               
End Sub
```

Output is

`(1234.00.01.01, 5678.03`

`and 1234.00.02 excluding)`

Expected output

`1234.00.01.01`

`5678.03`

`1234.00.02`

Answer (score 1):

You won't need capture groups, so neither would you need to loop `Submatches` here, see if the following pattern works for you:

```
(?=(?:.*\n?)*\bexcluding\)$)\d+(?:\.\d+)*
```

The nested non-capture group inside the positive lookahead looks a bit odd, but the problem is that VBScript does [not have an option to make the dot match line break characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html) unlike the very similar JavaScript counterpart.

So, here is an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xn21Hh/1/) and below a breakdown of the pattern:

- `(?=` - Positive lookahead:
  *`(?:` - Non-capture group:
  * `.*\n?` - 0+ times any character but newline followed by an optional newline character.
  * `)*` - Close non-capture group and match 0+ times up to:

  - `\b` - Word-boundary.
  - `excluding` - Literally match "excluding".
  - `\)` - A literal closing paranthesis.
  - `$` - End string anchor.
  - `)` - Close positive lookaehad.
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\.\d+` - A literal dot followed by 1+ digits.
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match it 0+ times.

**Note:** The `MultiLine` property of the regex object is left out in the code below. This is on purpose because we don't need it and thus it is set to `FALSE` by default. This is important, because if we set this to `TRUE` the start and end string anchors will also match positions after or before newline characters.

```
Sub Test_nLine()

Dim oRegexp, iStr As String, colMatch, objMatch

iStr = "(1234.00.01.01, 5678.03 " & vbLf & " and 1234.00.02 excluding)"

Set oRegexp = New regexp
With oRegexp
    .Pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?=(?:.*\n*)*\bexcluding\)$)"
    .Global = True
    If .Test(iStr) = True Then
        Set colMatch = .Execute(iStr)
        For Each objMatch In colMatch
            Debug.Print objMatch
        Next
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Important to note that I also included the `Test` method to catch the occurences where no match would be found prior to setting a `MatchCollection2` object to prevent error messages. The above will now print:

```
1234.00.01.01
5678.03
1234.00.02
```

---

**EDIT:** Due to backtracking, the `Test` method can take very long if your string does **not** end with "excluding)". Therefor I'd advise to use the `Like` operator in that case:

```
Sub Test_nLine()

Dim oRegexp, iStr As String, colMatch, objMatch

iStr = "(1234.00.01.01, 5678.03" & vbLf & "and 1234.00.02 excluding)"

If iStr Like "*excluding)" Then
    Set oRegexp = New regexp
    With oRegexp
        .Pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)*"
        .Global = True
        If .Test(iStr) = True Then
            Set colMatch = .Execute(iStr)
            For Each objMatch In colMatch
                Debug.Print objMatch
            Next
        End If
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, First of all thank you for your quick reply.
Well, if the expression ends with the word excluded, let it do the job.

Comment: @wonderfullife, I'm not quite sure what you meant by that last sentence.

Comment: Hi again,
if the sentence ends excluding,
let the pattern above work.
if the sentence does not end excluding
don't work.                                                                                                                               Sample;
iStr = "(1234.00.01.01, 5678.03" & vbLf & "and 1234.00.02)"
result = ""

Comment: @wonderfullife, I edited the answer. Can you let me know if this has worked for you now?

Comment: iStr = "(1234.00.01.01, 5678.03" & vbLf & "and 1234.00.02)"
When I write as Debug, if .test (iStr) = True Then it is waited for about 2 minutes and then it comes out from if.

iStr = "(1234.00.01.01, 5678.03 " & vbLf & " and 1234.00.02 excluding)"

gives the correct result.

Comment: That is regular expressions for you @wonderfullife. Unfortunately I don't see a way around this if you persist on using expressions. If it would have been my choice I'd use string functions to test if your string ends with "excluding)". This will save you precious time. See my edited answer for an alternative.

Comment: @wonderfullife, if it has now been working. You should consider to accept an answer. Note that RonRosenfeld also included a nice answer with a lookahead that is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, from your question, why you need to test for "excluding", but to just extract your digit-dot strings, yes, you can do it with regex and no lookaround:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test_nLine()
Dim oRegexp, iStr, colMatch, objMatch
Set oRegexp = New regexp
With oRegexp
    .Pattern = "\b\d[.\d]+\d\b"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True 'This is irrelevant since we don't use the "^$" in this regex

End With
iStr = "(1234.00.01.01, 5678.03 " & vbLf & " and 1234.00.02 excluding)"
Set colMatch = oRegexp.Execute(iStr)
For Each objMatch In colMatch
    Debug.Print objMatch
Next
End Sub
```

***output***

```
1234.00.01.01
5678.03
1234.00.02
```

If, for some reason, you want to return the digit.dot strings if and only if the string ends with "`excluding)`" then change:

```
.MultiLine = False
.Pattern = "(?=[\s\S]*excluding\)$)(?:\b\d[.\d]+\d)"
```

This will return "nothing" if it does not match the pattern.
If you want to return something else in the case of a no-match, instead of `.test` I suggest just checking that `colMatch.Count > 0`

Comment: A much better lookahead construct than mine, that's for sure.

Comment: It is a bit different having the lookahead at the beginning of the regex <g>

Comment: It's not just that, it's a better construct in general. See the demo I included in my answer. I did have the lookahead before the captured pattern. having it still in the VBA sample is more a typo than on purpose. Yet yours takes less than 500 steps while mine....well takes many more =). Though I finally decided against a lookahead completely since I just used the `Like` operator.

Comment: Note though that you are forcing the pattern to be at least 2 digits. A single digit won't be captured. Than again, that may not even be relevant to OP.

Comment: @JvdV  The pattern is that the string starts with a digit, ends with a digit, and has at least one digit or dot in between. That is consistent with all of the patterns shown by the OP. If that is not the case, I would need to see more representative patterns.

Comment: Dear Ron Rosenfeld
Your solution is very good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did it as follows but can I do it with regex?

```
Sub Test_nLine_()

Dim oRegexp, iStr As String, colMatch, objMatch

iStr = "(1234.00.01.01, 5678.03 " & vbLf & " and 1234.00.02 excluding)"
'iStr = "(1234.00.01.01, 5678.03 " & vbLf & " and 1234.00.02)"

Set oRegexp = New regexp
With oRegexp
    .pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)*"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    If InStr(iStr, "excluding") > 0 Then
        If .test(iStr) = True Then
            Set colMatch = oRegexp.Execute(iStr)
            For Each objMatch In colMatch
                Debug.Print objMatch
            Next
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ImportWordTable_Regex()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim file, txtDOC
Dim arrPattern(1 To 2) As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set regexp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

regexp.IgnoreCase = True
'regexp.MultiLine = True
regexp.MultiLine = False
regexp.Global = True

arrPattern(1) = "(\d{2,4}[\d,.]*)\s(.+)\s(\d[\d,.]*)\s([\sA-Za-z.]*)"
arrPattern(2) = "(?=[\s\S]*excluding)(?:\b\d[.\d]+\d)"


file = "C:\Test\testDOC.docx"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:D1") = Array("Nr", "Explanation", "Amount", "Unit")
iTable = 1:   iRow = 2

Set wdDoc = GetObject(path & file)
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

For Each oTbl In wdDoc.Tables
Set wrdTbl = wdDoc.Tables(iTable)
ColCount = wrdTbl.Columns.Count
RowCount = wrdTbl.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To RowCount
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    txtDOC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(wdDoc.Range(wrdTbl.Cell(i, _ 
               1).Range.Start, wrdTbl.Cell(i, ColCount).Range.End - 1).Text)
    For Each xData In arrPattern
        regexp.Pattern = xData
        
        If regexp.test(txtDOC) Then
            If arrPattern(2) = xData Then
                Set colMatch = regexp.Execute(txtDOC)
                For Each objMatch In colMatch
                    Range("A" & iRow) = objMatch
                    iRow = iRow + 1
                Next
            Else
                For Each retVal In regexp.Execute(txtDOC)
                    Range("A" & iRow) = retVal.Submatches(0)
                    Range("B" & iRow) = retVal.Submatches(1)
                    Range("C" & iRow) = retVal.Submatches(2) + 0
                    Range("D" & iRow) = retVal.Submatches(3)
                    iRow = iRow + 1
                Next
            End If
            tmptxtDOC = Replace(txtDOC, "  ", Empty)   'for err.Number = 5941
        End If
    Next
Next i
iTable = iTable + 1
    
Next oTbl

wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=0

Set wdDoc = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    If Err.Number = 5941 Then
            txtDOC = Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(wrdTbl.Cell(i, 
1).Range.Text)) & " " & tmptxtDOC
            tmptxtDOC = ""
            Err.Clear
            Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Hi,
I'm trying to learn new Regex.
I would like to expand my question a little more.
I have a word table as below.

With the code above, I get the result below. Also below is the result I want.
I will be grateful to friends to help.

| Nr | Explanation | Amount | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234.00.00.01 | Abcd | 1,2 | Kg |
|  | (Efgh) |  |  |
| 1234.00.00.02 | Ghij | 0,8 | Liter |
| 1234.01 | Klmn | 0,8 | Liter |
| 1234.02 | Opsx (1234.02.02 and 1234.02.99 excluding) | 0,9 | Liter |
| 1234.05.00 | Other |  |  |
|  | 1234.05.00.01 | 0,5 | Liter |
|  | 1234.05.10.01 | 0,6 | Liter |

Output: (4 columns)

`1234.00.00.01  | Abcd   | 1,2   |   Kg`

`1234.00.00.02  | Ghij   | 0,8   |   Liter`

`1234.01        | Abcd   | 0,8   |   Liter`

`1234.02        | Opsx   | 0,9   |   Liter`

`1234.02        |        |       |`

`1234.02.02     |        |       |`

`1234.02.99     |        |       |`

Expected output: (4 columns)

`1234.00.00.01  | Abcd   | 1,2   |   Kg`

`1234.00.00.02  | Ghij   | 0,8   |   Liter`

`1234.01        | Abcd   | 0,8   |   Liter`

`1234.02        | Opsx   | 0,9   |   Liter`

`1234.02.02     |        |       |`

`1234.02.99     |        |       |`

`1234.05.00.01  |        | 0,5   |   Liter`

`1234.05.10.01  |        | 0,5   |   Liter`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows.
However, I did not like it very much.

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234.02 | Opsx (1234.02.02 and 1234.02.99 excluding |

`1234.02.02     |        |       |`

`1234.02.99     |        |       |`

How do I change the code below to get the code above?
The values in the 1st column will not get from the excluding ending with the word exclude.

arrPattern(2) = "(?=[\s\S]*excluding)(?:\b\d[.\d]+\d)"

```
For i = 2 To RowCount
            On Error GoTo ErrHandler
            txtDOC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(wdDoc.Range(wrdTbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Start, _
                         wrdTbl.Cell(i, ColCount).Range.End - 1).Text)
            txtDOC2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(wrdTbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text)
            For Each xData In arrPattern
                regexp.Pattern = xData
                If regexp.test(txtDOC) Then
                    If arrPattern(2) = xData Then
                        Set colMatch = regexp.Execute(txtDOC2)
                        For Each objMatch In colMatch
                            Range("A" & iRow) = objMatch
                            iRow = iRow + 1
                        Next
                    Else
                        For Each retVal In regexp.Execute(txtDOC)
                            'i = i + 1
                            Range("A" & iRow) = retVal.Submatches(0)
                            Range("B" & iRow) = retVal.Submatches(1)
                            Range("C" & iRow) = retVal.Submatches(2) + 0
                            Range("D" & iRow) = retVal.Submatches(3)
                            iRow = iRow + 1
                        Next
                    End If
                    tmptxtDOC = Replace(txtDOC, "  ", Empty)
                End If
            Next
        Next i
```